# Remove libgcc_s dependency from gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

I have installed gcc-7.1.0 from source based on: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html to use a newer gcc.

The compiled binaries have an extra dependency with `libgcc`:

```
$ ldd a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd85fd000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x000000365b400000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000365a800000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000301ae00000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000365b000000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000365a000000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003659c00000)
```

I didn't choose any particular configuration options (other than `--prefix`) and installed with defaults. Looking at the `config.log`, it appears that configuration decided it couldn't do so by default. Relevant parts:

```
configure:5038: checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
configure:5055: g++ -o conftest -g -O2   -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc conftest.cpp  >&5
g++: unrecognized option '-static-libstdc++'
conftest.cpp:11:2: error: #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
configure:5055: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| #if (__GNUC__ < 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5)
| #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
| #endif
| int main() {}
configure:5059: result: no
```

(The `g++` available - used above - is a bit old: g++ 4.1.2 if that's relevant).

I am compiling only C code. So, if there's no static linking support `-static-libstdc++`, that's not an issue. But I don't understand why `libgcc` is tied with `-static-libstdc++`.

`libgcc_s.so.1` isn't always available on all machines. While I can install it, I don't want this extra requirement on my customers. Is there any way I can remove this dependency?

While using `-static-libgcc` switch does get remove `libgcc_s.so.1`, I am looking for a way to let gcc itself do this. If that means re-configuring and reinstalling gcc, it is fine by me.

P.S.: I also have to follow the workarounds from here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61955 as the machine is a bit old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't understand why libgcc is tied with -static-libstdc++.

It isn't. That configure test controls whether the intermediate compiler during bootstrap is linked statically or dynamically, it has nothing to do with the executables produced by the final GCC.

> `libgcc_s.so.1` isn't always available on all machines. While I can install it, I don't want this extra requirement on my customers. Is there any way I can remove this dependency?

IMHO it should be installed anyway, *lots* of packages depend on it.

The executables depend on libgcc because they use something from that library. Link with `-static-libgcc` to use `libgcc.a` instead of `libgcc_s.so`. If you want that to happen automatically either install a wrapper script around your new GCC that always adds it to the command-line arguments, or use a custom [specs file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) that always adds that option, e.g. by configuring GCC with something like:

```
--with-specs=%{!shared-libgcc:-static-libgcc}
```

This should mean that `-static-libgcc` is always used implicitly unless `-shared-libgcc` is explicitly provided on the command line. I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score -3):

gcc-7.1.0 depends on libgcc_s.so.1 (Or the static), **version 7.1.0**, which must be supplied with the "gcc-7.1.0 package".

Easily done when gcc is supplied as a self contained folder. (gcc7/) Which is often the most convenient solution for an extra compiler.

Ref. http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/
→ → http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/gcc-pass2.html (The LFS method is recommended by the gcc people.)

Example, --prefix=/opt/gcc7 or --prefix=/usr/localgcc7

`../gcc-7.1.0/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc7 --program-suffix=7 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib`

Making the links : `cd /usr/bin/ && ln -s [path-to]/gcc7/bin/gcc7 && ln -s [path-to]/gcc7/bin/g++7`

Also very easy to create a package.deb, package.rpm from the above.

? Who would want to be without a c++ compiler ? Suggest: Include g++.

Comment: _"The LFS method is recommended by the gcc people."_ [citation needed]

Comment: The question is about binaries produced by the OP's new GCC, not how to package the new GCC itself.